# In Java, I'm trying to use classes to take the average of three values from user input

Tags: java

I've got the basics down, I think, but I'm stuck at trying to get user input. I've been trying to use the scanner class to get the input, but I don't think I am using it correctly in this context. The program is attempting to print the average.

https://pastebin.com/BDhT75PP

Comment: You are not using the scanner after you create it. Take a look at its documentation for how to use it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Don't link to your code, paste your (relevant) code here. Check out [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have to input the data first. Try creating temporary variables to store the input values and do:

```
int temp1 = in.nextInt();
int temp2 = in.nextInt();
int temp3 = in.nextInt();
```

to input the numbers. After that, then you can call your set functions.

If this helps, please consider marking it as an answer to your question.

Thanks